# Rjags with error "Unknown variable state"

Tags: r, rjags

When I used rjags to build my model, I got the error "Compilation error on line 18.
Unknown variable state
Either supply values for this variable with the data
or define it  on the left hand side of a relation." What's the error with my code?

```
model_string <- "model {
  dur <- Time[1]
  state[1] ~ dcat(pi)
  for (i in 1:N-1) {
    Speed[i] ~ dnorm(mu_speed[state[i]], prec_speed[state[i]])
    Course[i] ~ dnorm(mu_course[state[i]], prec_course[state[i]])
    Rota[1,1] <- cos(Course[i])
    Rota[1,2] <- -sin(Course[i])
    Rota[2,1] <- sin(Course[i])
    Rota[2,2] <- cos(Course[i])
    # Rota <- matrix(c(cos(Course[i]), -sin(Course[i]), sin(Course[i]), cos(Course[i])),nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
    Rota_before <- Position[i,] / sqrt(sum(Position[i,]^2))
    Distance <- a[state[i]] * Speed[i] * Rota_before %*% Rota * Time[i]
    Position[i+1,] ~ dmnorm(Position[i,] + Distance, sigma_position)
    
    q <- 1 - qnorm(dur+Time[i+1], mu_time[state[i]], prec_time[state[i]])
    p <- c(q,q,q)
    p[state[i]] <- 1 - q
    p <- A[state[i],] * p / sum(A[state[i],] * p)
    state[i+1] ~ dcat(p)
    
    dur <- ifelse(state[i]==state[i+1], dur+Time[i+1], Time[i+1])
  }
  

  
  Speed[N] ~ dnorm(mu_speed[state[N]], prec_speed[state[N]])
  Course[N] ~ dnorm(mu_course[state[N]], prec_speed[state[N]])
  
  
  pi ~ ddirich(c(1,1,1))
  mu_speed[1] ~ dnorm(2, 1.0/100.0) T(0,)
  mu_speed[2] ~ dnorm(30, 1.0/100.0) T(mu_speed[1],)
  mu_speed[3] ~ dnorm(50, 1.0/100.0) T(mu_speed[2],)
  R[1,1] = 1
  R[1,2] = 0
  R[2,1] = 0
  R[2,2] = 1
  sigma_position ~ dwish(R,3)
  
  for (j in 1:3) {
    prec_speed[j] ~ dgamma(1.0/2.0, 1.0*1.0/2.0)
    Course[j] ~ dunif(0,2*pi)
    prec_course[j] ~ dgamma(1.0/2.0, 1.0*1.0/2.0)
    a[j] ~ dunif(1e-6, 1e-5)
    mu_time[j] ~ dnorm(100, 1000)
    prec_time[j] ~ dgamma(1.0/2.0, 1.0*1.0/2.0)
    A[j,1:3] ~ ddirich(c(50, 50, 50))
  }
}"
```

I really don't know where it went wrong. Does anybody could help me please? Thank you a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

You have this line in your code:

```
Rota <- matrix(c(cos(Course[i]), -sin(Course[i]), sin(Course[i]), 
               cos(Course[i])),nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
```

which is R syntax, not JAGS syntax (although lots of JAGS syntax *resembles* R syntax, it's actually a completely different language).  It's been a while since I did any JAGS coding, but based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50009083/multiplying-a-vector-of-parameters-by-a-matrix-of-independent-variables-in-jags) I think you probably want something like

```
Rota[1,1] <-  cos(Course[i])
Rota[1,2] <- -sin(Course[i])
Rota[2,1] <-  sin(Course[i])
Rota[2,2] <-  cos(Course[i])
```

JAGS should figure out that you want `Rota` to be a matrix, and what its dimensions are, automatically.

(There is an example on p. 11 of the [JAGS user manual](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mcmc-jags/files/Manuals/4.x/jags_user_manual.pdf/download).)

---

With respect to

> Unknown variable `state` Either supply values for this variable with the data or define it on the left hand side of a relation

I'm not *quite* sure why `state` isn't recognized ...

Comment: Thanks you a lot. But after fixing this error, I got another error "Compilation error on line 18.
Unknown variable state
Either supply values for this variable with the data
or define it  on the left hand side of a relation."

Comment: This is turning into a [chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions); if you keep updating your question to incorporate my answers and then ask about the *next* problem, this could go on for a long time ...